# How to get properties of association object in Alfresco using json.ftl

Tags: javascript, json, alfresco, freemarker, alfresco-share

I have a type abc:appDate.  It has a property abc:dateTime an association to self ie.,

```
<association name="abc:nextAppDate">
<title>Next App Date</title>
<source>
    <mandatory>false</mandatory>
    <many>false</many>
</source>
<target>
    <class>abc:appDate</class>
    <mandatory>false</mandatory>
    <many>true</many>
</target>
</association>
```

**How to get properties of association object using json.ftl?**

I was trying to get properties of association as below, but getting "Error during processing of the template 'Expression result.assocs[\"abc:nextAppDate\"] is undefined"

```
<#macro dateFormat date>${date?string("dd MMM yyyy")}</#macro>
    <#escape x as jsonUtils.encodeJSONString(x)>
    {
        "nodeRef": "${result.nodeRef}", 
        "date": "<@dateFormat result.properties["abc:dateTime"] />",
        "nextDate": [
        <#list result.assocs["abc:nextAppDate"] as childKey>
        {
        "date": "<@dateFormat childKey.properties["abc:dateTime"] />"               
        }
        <#if child_has_next>,</#if>
        </#list>
        ]
    }
    </#escape>
```

Comment: Sorry if you already thought of this but have you verified that the node you are testing against actually has at least one of those associations and that it was created with the correct qname?

Comment: You are right Jeff. There was no association for one of the two nodes I created for testing :) So, what I did was added code to check if "result.assocs["abc:nextAppDate"]" is null as shown in my own answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the code needed a null check. The following code is working

```
<#macro dateFormat date>${date?string("dd MMM yyyy")}</#macro>
    <#escape x as jsonUtils.encodeJSONString(x)>
    {
        "nodeRef": "${result.nodeRef}", 
        "date": "<@dateFormat result.properties["abc:dateTime"] />",
        "nextDate": [
        <#if (result.assocs["abc:nextAppDate"])??>
        <#list result.assocs["abc:nextAppDate"] as childKey>
        {
        "date": "<@dateFormat childKey.properties["abc:dateTime"] />"               
        }
        <#if child_has_next>,</#if>
        </#list>
        <#else>
    </#if>
        ]
    }
    </#escape>
```